# False Duplicate Report

Tags: discussion, bug

Some user and a moderator marked [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337411/who-or-whom-in-by-other-people-whom-i-know/392135#392135) as a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400197/how-do-i-choose-between-who-or-whom-when-the-subject-pronoun-is-murky), even though the "duplicate" was asked a year before the "original" was.

What's up with that?

Comment: Duplication is not date-dependent. If a later question is better or has better answers, that can (and should) be the target. The question closed as a duplicate acts as a signpost to the best answers.

Comment: It's no big thing. Whatever the timing, sometimes things aren't noticed until well after the fact. In this case the more trafficked and highly voted answered one was kept as the original.

Comment: @Mitch Thank you! Answers this completely.